# pip install xgboost with error Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 on mac (Python 2.7)

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pip, xgboost

When I executed:

> pip install xgboost

I got this:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/w4/w49s3mn91plbhyjwf8qjkpxc0000gn/T/pip-build-61dms1/xgboost/

Here is my log:

```
liumengyaodeMacBook-Pro:~ liumengyao$ pip install xgboost
Collecting xgboost
Using cached xgboost-0.6a2.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
rm -f -rf build build_plugin lib bin *~ */*~ */*/*~ */*/*/*~ */*.o */*/*.o */*/*/*.o xgboost
clang-omp++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/learner.o src/learner.cc >build/learner.d
/bin/sh: clang-omp++: command not found
make: *** [build/learner.o] Error 127
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
clang-omp++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/logging.o src/logging.cc >build/logging.d
/bin/sh: clang-omp++: command not found
make: *** [build/logging.o] Error 127
-----------------------------
Building multi-thread xgboost failed
Start to build single-thread xgboost
rm -f -rf build build_plugin lib bin *~ */*~ */*/*~ */*/*/*~ */*.o */*/*.o */*/*/*.o xgboost
clang-omp++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/learner.o src/learner.cc >build/learner.d
/bin/sh: clang-omp++: command not found
make: *** [build/learner.o] Error 127
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
clang-omp++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/logging.o src/logging.cc >build/logging.d
/bin/sh: clang-omp++: command not found
make: *** [build/logging.o] Error 127
Successfully build single-thread xgboost
If you want multi-threaded version
See additional instructions in doc/build.md
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/w4/w49s3mn91plbhyjwf8qjkpxc0000gn/T/pip-build-61dms1/xgboost/setup.py", line 29, in <module>
    LIB_PATH = libpath['find_lib_path']()
  File "/private/var/folders/w4/w49s3mn91plbhyjwf8qjkpxc0000gn/T/pip-build-61dms1/xgboost/xgboost/libpath.py", line 45, in find_lib_path
    'List of candidates:\n' + ('\n'.join(dll_path)))
__builtin__.XGBoostLibraryNotFound: Cannot find XGBoost Libarary in the candicate path, did you install compilers and run build.sh in root path?
List of candidates:
/private/var/folders/w4/w49s3mn91plbhyjwf8qjkpxc0000gn/T/pip-build-61dms1/xgboost/xgboost/libxgboost.so
/private/var/folders/w4/w49s3mn91plbhyjwf8qjkpxc0000gn/T/pip-build-61dms1/xgboost/xgboost/../../lib/libxgboost.so
/private/var/folders/w4/w49s3mn91plbhyjwf8qjkpxc0000gn/T/pip-build-61dms1/xgboost/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/w4/w49s3mn91plbhyjwf8qjkpxc0000gn/T/pip-build-61dms1/xgboost/
```

I have tried several methods:

1. python ez_setup.py (the file downloaded from website)
2. pip install --upgrade setuptools
3. pip install distribute

But I still cannot solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I had an issue and realized pip was out of date. Solved my issue.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install xgboost
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I installed it for Python 3.7:

```
brew install gcc@7
pip3 install
```